# R Kernel on VSCode Jupyter Notebook not appearing

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel, rstudio

I'm trying to use an R Kernel on a Jupyter Notebook on VSCode, and the R Kernel is not appearing. I can only see Python.

I opened R studio, R in powershell, and R in VScode terminal and tried running the following code:

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
# Also tried: IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
```

Both ran successfully.
If I run "jupyter kernelspec list"
you can see:

```
ir:
C:\Users\000\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir
ir33:
C:\Users\000\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir33
python3:
C:\Users\000\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

However, when I navigate back to VSCode, open a new Jupyter notebook, and try to switch the kernel from Python to R, nothing appears.

When I run "Jupyter Notebook" from command prompt and the Jupyter Notebook web browser opens up, I can see both the "R" and "R 3.3" kernel appear, and they connect and run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by updating my visual studio. I was getting a popup saying my visual studio needed an update, so i updated it, and with the new update, there was an option to choose a jupyter kernel which showed my R kernels. I'm not sure if this was a Cache issue on the Visual Studio side which was solved by the reload after the update, or simply an issue that was fixed in an update.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for letting others know.

Comment: Do you know to which Version of VS Code you upgraded?